# Viterbi decoder

Tags: encoding, decoding, viterbi

Does anyone know for any good resource on the web or book where the explanation for Viterbi decoder or a tutorial on how to decode a received bit sequence by using trellis diagram could be found?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good explanation can be found on [1-core](http://www.1-core.com/library/comm/viterbi/).

Wikipedia, of course, has plenty of [background information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viterbi_decoder).

There is actually a [website](http://www.spiral.net/software/viterbi.html) which will generate viterbi decoder software for you. How cool is that?

Answer (score 1):

[Digital Communications: Fundamentals and Applications - Bernard Sklar](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130847887) perhaps.